# Quickblox QBChat delegate "chatRoomDidReceiveMessage" Calling twice when message recieved

Tags: ios, dialog, chat, message, quickblox

Quickblox  Qbchat delegate chatRoomDidReceiveMessage is calling multiple times.

In normal case it is being called only once.
but when i go back from chat page and join the dialog and come to chat.

chatRoomDidReceiveMessage will be called exactly same number of times i join the dialog.

Can it be a problem due to may be i am joining the dialog multiple times or something like that?

Comment: Please specify sdk version you are using

Comment: Am using version 2.6.5

Comment: You cannot join same dialog multiple times, it will simply returl "already joined" error. chatRoomDidReceiveMessage may be called twice cause message for group dialog can be updated by server. Were there more then twice calls?

Comment: Yes like i said the number of calls are equal to how many times i go back and come to chat page.

For e.g if i go back 7 times then it will call 7 times

Comment: Check out how many entries in [[QBChat instance] delegates] array when you are receiving callback 7 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped !!!